# Wrong resolution after login with Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: xubuntu, resolution

after updating to Xubuntu 13.10, I cannot log in with my normal user anymore. When logging in, a short while after typing the password, the screen refreshes and suddenly is all garbled, just like on old monitors if you set a wrong resolution or refresh rate.

Logging in as a new user works fine. No resolution problems. It's like a wrong resolution is stored by the old user, but I cannot figure out in which files this resolution is stored, and - obviously - I can't check in the settings manager either, as I can't get to it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved. Fixed it by deleting ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel/displays.xml

Comment: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest you set the resolution after saving the original configuration file (a best practice)

> cd /etc/default ; cp -an grub grub.sav ; nano grub

In nano grub above, change the value of GRUB_GFXMODE= to 1024x768 or some other compatible resolution, and add the line

> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

Then run

> update-grub

and reboot after, which should resolve the problem.